# Angular2 Vladivostok Router: how to pass on "debug" query string

Tags: angular, router, query-string, vladivostok

I'm using @angular/router version 3 (called [Vladivostok](https://github.com/angular/vladivostok)). In my app, I expose some lower-level details, whether from backend or frontend components, if I append a `debug=FLAGS` to query string. But when I navigate away (e.g. next page in a table view), the query string is lost.

Can I add some sort of configuration option or similar which will help me forward this string along on all `[routerLink]` entries?

Or if not, can I extend the router? Where would be a good place to start

Comment: There was an issue reported recently about this AFAIR but vladivostok was integrated into the angular repository and I can't find any issues from vladivostok anymore. Did you try with Angular2 RC.3?

Comment: No, still on RC.1. But even with RC.3 - I simply don't know the syntax for such a thing and cannot find it in the docs.

Comment: Syntax for what? If you add them to the URL try `http://someurl;debug=FLAGS`. In routerlink use `<a [routerLink]="..." [queryParams]="{debug: FLAGS}">`

Comment: No, what I asked if there's an option to _always pass `debug` query string as is_. Or if not, how can I extend the router to do it manually instead?

Comment: I guess you somewhere, or somehow want to set `debug=...` or *not* set it. And you want this queryParams (if set) to be retained even after clicking some routerLink or executing `this.router.navigate(...)`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Then we are back to square one :D (my first comment) That's what the issue was about I couldn't find because the vladivostok repo doesn't contain any issues anymore and I don't remember enought to know what to search for which is difficult in a repo with 1400 open issues but was easy in vladivostok with ~25 :-/